# In SpringBoot, binding query parameters to an intermediate Java object before converting

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am currently using SpringBoot 1.3.5 to process web form submissions.

I want to have my controller handler for a particular request supply a Java object that has gone through the steps of:

- binding the query parameters to a Java object
- validating this data
- enriching this validated data - basically converting the bound object into another type which has additional data.

The intention is to allow me to keep the various bits of logic in specific locations, making it cleaner and more testable as well as have separate types representing the form submission and the domain objects I'm working on in my application.

What I am able to do:

- I can get Spring to bind various request parameters to a single bean that has those named parameters as fields.
- I can get Spring to convert automatically by having a converter that implements the Converter interface.

However, I cannot get things to work quite as I would like; I can only have the converter be called when the converter's source and target types are the same. I could just inject a ConversionService and perform the conversion manually as a first step in handling the request, but possibly there's a better solution that does it automatically?

So I have:

```
public class FooRequest {
    @Valid private List<Bar> bars;
    @Size(min = 10, max = 10) private String requestCode;

    private EnrichedData enrichedData;
}

@Controller
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = POST)
    public String test(@Valid FooRequest request, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
        FooRequest enrichedRequest = enrich(request);
        // do some stuff....
        return "test";
    }
}
```

Maybe this test helps clarify intent:

```
@Test public void () throws Exception {
    mvc.perform(
            post("/test")
                    .session(createSession())
                    .param("requestCode", "42")
                    .param("bar[0].a", "123")
                    .param("bar[0].b", "456"));
    .... 
}
```

I then moved the enrichment to a converter registered in my `AppConfig` (which extends Spring's `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`):

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = POST)
    public String test(@Valid FooRequest request, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
        // do some stuff....
        return "test";
    }
}

public class FooConverter  implements Converter<FooRequest, FooRequest> {
    @Override public FooRequest convert(final FooRequest foo) {
        // do some stuff and create a request from the form
        ....
        return enriched(foo)
    }
}
```

What I would like is the ability to introduce a FooForm type, so that I end up with this:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = POST)
    public String test(@Valid FooRequest request, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
        // do some stuff....
        return "test";
    }
}

public class FooConverter  implements Converter<FooForm, FooRequest> {
    @Override public FooRequest convert(final FooForm form) {
        // do some stuff and create a request from the form
        ....
        return convertIntoRequest(form)
    }
}

public class FooForm {
    @Valid private List<Bar> bars;
    @Size(min = 10, max = 10) private String requestCode;
}

public class FooRequest {
    private List<Bar> bars;
    private String requestCode;

    private EnrichedData enrichedData;
```

}

Thoughts?

Comment: A convert is, as the name implies, a converter (i.e. convert a String to a Date for instance).. It isn't an enricher, at least that is not what it is designed for. So you are trying to use the wrong thing for something. What is wrong with doing manual enrichment, or create something yourself that does the enriching.